# Popped wrong app context when using gevent.spawn

Tags: python, flask, gevent

I am trying to run multiple concurrent downstream requests using gevent in my flask application.

I have:

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(thread=False)
from flask import Flask, request, g

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
```

and the following code:

```
def f1(self):
    @copy_current_request_context
    def _test(t):
        time.sleep(t)

        r = requests.get(
            'https://webhook.site/d14a41a6-9c6a-4da0-bbe6-3cc660daea3d', params=dict(word='test')
        )

        return r.status_code


    jobs = [gevent.spawn(_test, 5), gevent.spawn(_test, 10)]

    results = [job.value for job in gevent.joinall(jobs)]

    return None
```

If the second _test is taking longer than the first one I am getting a Popped wrong app context error.

If I add another method like:

```
    @copy_current_request_context
    def _test_bis(t):
        from random import randint
        time.sleep(t)

        r = requests.get(
            'https://webhook.site/d14a41a6-9c6a-4da0-bbe6-3cc660daea3d', params=dict(word='test')
        )

        return r.status_code
```

and use it like that:

```
jobs = [gevent.spawn(_test_bis, 5), gevent.spawn(_test, 10)]
```

I don't have any error.

Any idea how I could work around that issue?

Answer (score 3):

Thi has to do with [Flask's application context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/). When you spin up multiple greenlets using spawn, Flask doesn't know which app is the "current" app. You've made use of `@copy_current_request_context` decorator but, that only copy request context and gives a new app context to all bg threads.

To avoid this, you could create one to pass the current app context with closure:

```
def copy_current_app_context(f):
    from flask.globals import _app_ctx_stack
    appctx = _app_ctx_stack.top
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        with appctx:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _
```

Or you could choose to wrap your thread code in a `test_request_context` so you have access to context locals:

```
def f1(self):
    with app.test_request_context():
        def _test(t):
            time.sleep(t)

            r = requests.get(
                'https://webhook.site/d14a41a6-9c6a-4da0-bbe6-3cc660daea3d', params=dict(word='test')
            )

        return r.status_code


    jobs = [gevent.spawn(_test, 5), gevent.spawn(_test, 10)]

    results = [job.value for job in gevent.joinall(jobs)]

    return None
```

it's worth pointing out that the thread will have a different context than the original request. should you need any interesting request data, it's important to extract that before spawning the thread.